# read data from pdf files using c#

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have this question. I have 5 PDFs having around 38,000 objective questions. So i want to make an application which imports this questions and save it into database and then give interface to the user for choosing question with four objective. I used `itextsharp` to read from PDFs as a chunk and also line by line. The content after reading is scattered and i cannot figure out a sequence by which i can split or differentiate between the question and the four objectives. Is there any better way by which I can import data from PDFs?? The content in PDFs is in tabular format. Below are the images of Input PDF File and the Output Window. 
[image: Input PDF file]
[image: Output in the Windows form]

Comment: have u taken whole pdf in one string?

Comment: Could you show the resulting string that you extracted from the PDF and what information do you want to parse from it?

Comment: @freelancer i tried taking it in one string and also tried taking it into an array splitting by \n

Comment: @DarinDimitrov i m posting snapshots of the pdf and the resulting string. Please check
Pdf file (http://s8.postimage.org/owm0hsej9/Qbank.jpg)

resulting string in Window(http://s13.postimage.org/4toy70lqf/Resulting_String.jpg)

Comment: PDF files are not meant to be used as a data storage format, if you still have a choice on this, I would recommend using another format such as xml or even a plain text file.

Comment: @yms I m not using PDF as data storage format.I have those files as a raw data.. i want a way to save that data in any of the databases so that i can use it in my app.